# Custom Font Face does not render on other computers on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I recently started a project on Wordpress where the custom font face I implemented doesn't seem to work on other computers.

The website is [grubexotic.com](http://grubexotic.com)

I created a child theme, and simply put the font face css within the style.css file for the child theme.

```
/*
Theme Name:   Grub Exotic
Theme URI:    https://www.elementor.com/
Description:  Grub Exotic using hello-elementor
Author:       Studio 8472
Author URI:   https://www.studio8472.com/
Template:     hello-elementor
Version:      1.0.0
Text Domain:  hello-elementor
*/

@font-face {
    font-family: "Arfelick Feather";
    src: url(https://www.grubexotic.com/wp-content/themes/grubexotic/fonts/arfelickfeather/Arfelick-Feather.eot) format("embedded-opentype"),
        url(https://www.grubexotic.com/wp-content/themes/grubexotic/fonts/arfelickfeather/Arfelick-Feather.otf) format("opentype"),
        url(https://www.grubexotic.com/wp-content/themes/grubexotic/fonts/arfelickfeather/Arfelick-Feather.svg) format("svg"),
        url(https://www.grubexotic.com/wp-content/themes/grubexotic/fonts/arfelickfeather/Arfelick-Feather.ttf) format("truetype"),
        url(https://www.grubexotic.com/wp-content/themes/grubexotic/fonts/arfelickfeather/Arfelick-Feather.woff) format("woff"),
        url(https://www.grubexotic.com/wp-content/themes/grubexotic/fonts/arfelickfeather/Arfelick-Feather.woff2) format("woff2");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have a custom html widget within Elementor where I'm simply calling the font family.

```
.comingsoon_header {
    z-index: 11;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-15deg);
    font-family: "Arfelick Feather"; 
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
    font-size: 10rem;
}
```

It seems to work everywhere on my computer, but any other device it doesn't seem to work. I'm encountering this issue with more than one project as well and its a little frustrating as I feel like this shouldn't be such a big issue and just a simple implementation. I'm hoping its just something I'm overlooking, what am I missing here?

If you need more info just let me know.

Comment: Sorry to ask a rather basic question - but you are actually using the child theme are you? Because the symptoms make it sound as though all is well on your computer because that font is loaded locally.

Comment: Yes, in the file managing via SFTP I added all six of those font types to a fonts folder that I created within the child theme directory. Those sources are where the actual font resides, if you copy and paste any of those it should download to your computer.

But yes I also have the font installed on my computer.

Comment: My query was whether the child theme is actually the theme that has been selected/is actually being used on the WP site.

Comment: @AHaworth When I access my themes, the only Grub Exotic theme in the list is active.

Comment: So do you need to activate the child theme - is the child theme appearing when you look at your themes in the dashboard?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my last comment. When I access my themes within the WP Dashboard, the Grub Exotic theme is there (the child theme) and active, with my custom screenshot and all.

Comment: Just looked at your site again and the font seems to be working -is it?

Comment: Yes! It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simply that the Global H1 was predominant, despite trying to use !important. Changing the global H1 to the custom font seemed to fix the issue.